# What is this insect looking like a wasp or an ant?

Tags: species-identification

It looks like a black wasp or big ant with wings. It produces no noise. It mostly sits at one place on the wall, does not move. The young (or another gender) form has unproportionally long back legs, making it look like a spider.

It has big head with big eyes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please include the size, location and weather details

Comment: These look like flies to me, but I'm not going to go any further than that.  Hopefully someone with more knowledge (and some idea of the location of these images..) will be able to get more specific.

Comment: To me they look like wasps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different kind of insects:

**First insect**

There is one pair of translucent wings (admittedly, the number of wing pairs is not visible from the photo), what tells us it must be some kind of fly (Diptera).
Further, the antenna is rather short, from what we can deduce it must be a [brachyceran fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachycera).
Even further, it has three segments, so we can conclude it is a member of the family ["soldier flies" (Stratiomyidae)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratiomyidae).

A friend (a dipterologist), upon seeing the photo, immediately argued it must be a ["black soldier fly (*Hermetia illucens*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermetia_illucens), a meanwhile cosmopolitan species that has gained economic importance in organic recycling.

---

**Second insect**

This one is much trickier, I think.
It *does* look like a [shore bug (Saldidae)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saldidae): the large eyes, slender and long antenna and legs, the flat and oval body - everything fits.
But shore bugs are tightly bound to their habitats (shores of all kinds of waterbodies). And at least in Europe, it is very unlikely (although not impossible) to find one inside a building.
Also, shore bugs are very agile and are fast runners, jumpers and flyers - what contradicts the OP's description ("It mostly sits [...], does not move").

Comment: I have also seet a variant of the first insect but much bigger (about 1.5x).

Answer (score 2):

This is a holometabolous insect, meaning with a complete metamorphosis. Therefore the second picture is not a young, a young would be a larva or a nymph, i.e., it would look nothing like a smaller version of an adult.
The insect on the second picture, if it is indeed the same species, is likely the male.